# What is wrong with my query?? It has no error at all

Tags: java, sql

I have a problem with my sql query in Java. As you can see below, the query is supposed to return rph_id but it returns only 0, so it only proceeds to the else method.

At first, I did not use prepareStatement but many suggest that I use prepareStatement. But it still won't work. After checking both suggestions, I think my problem is on the query but I don't know what.

```
    public class RphDAO{
    static int rph_id;

    public static RPHS getRph(RPHS rph) {    
                    try {
                        currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
                        ps=currentCon.prepareStatement("select * from rphs where rph_id=?");

                        ps.setInt(1, rph_id);
                        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

                        if (rs.next()) {
                            rs.getInt("rph_id");
                            rph.setRph_id(rph_id);
                            rph.setValid(true);
                        } else  {
                            rph.setValid(false);
                        }
                    }
                ...
                return rph;
            }
}
```

It should return an existing id, not 0.

Comment: Shouldn't you assign `rs.getInt("rph_id")` to some variable?

Comment: if it has no error, there is nothing wrong with it. your code doesn't produce output, so what output are you talking about? further more, we have no idea about the DB you access, so we can't really be the judge on whether or not the data returned by it is correct or not

Comment: @Eran it should be `int rph_id = rs.getInt("rph_id")` ?

Comment: @Stultuske sorry, I mean it should select an existing id, not 0.

Comment: The code you are showing ... doesnt return *anything*. That is why I suggested you read [mcve] and show us *all* relevant code, and a clear description what you expect.

Comment: *It has no error at all* - it will not even compile.

Comment: @GhostCat it returns `rph` the code is too long, I only take some part of it that has 'error'

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I already declare it before this getRph method.

Comment: As expected ... see my updated answer. Beyond that: dont provide an RPHS instance as parameter **and** return the same thing. Either your code creates a completely new instance and returns that, or it should update the object passed to it as parameter. But what you are doing here is simply very bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
if (rs.next()) {
  rs.getInt("rph_id");
  rph.setRph_id(rph_id);
  rph.setValid(true);
```

You **get** a value from the ResultSet `rs` ... to then throw that result away.

Probably you meant something like:

```
rph_id = rs.getInt("rph_id");
```

On the other hand, your request those entries that have rph_id==1, so I don't see what other value than `1` you expect to find here. Most likely, you want to look into **other** parts of that result set, and somehow pull those into variables/fields of some object.

It *seems* as if the OP is simply not familiar with using ResultSet, thus I think the real answer is: go and read a good [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) on this subject. You can't learn how to use a new API by trial and error. Read its documentation, or a good tutorial that shows you how to use it properly!

Comment: @GhostCat I'm sorry I will study the link you gave me but can you point out to me where did my code say ' select all columns for the row with rph_id = 1 '? I would like to check it again. Thank you in advanced

Comment: @GhostCat ohh I thought it was the same as insert query where the number 1 is the column position. Thank you

Comment: @hermanfarlan You are welcome. In case one of the answers was helpful, please dont forget about accepting it. And to delete all no-longer-required comments ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use COUNT instead in your sql since it is no point in setting the id if it is already correct and also use the id from the object given as parameter to the method for consistency.

```
public static RPHS getRph(RPHS rph) {    
    try {
        currentCon = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
        ps=currentCon.prepareStatement("select COUNT(*) from rphs where rph_id=?");

        ps.setInt(1, rph.getRph_id);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        int count = 0;
        if (rs.next()) {
            count = rs.getInt(1);
        }
        rph.setValid(count == 1);
    }
```